# UGC Video post to user profile

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to create a UGC post containing a Video for a LinkedIn personal profile (not a company). **When I create it as a company, it works fine**.

When I post this as a user, it fails:

```
POST https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts
Body:
{
    "author": "urn:li:person:<profile-urn>",
    "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
    "specificContent": {
        "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
            "media": [
                {
                    "media": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:<video-urn>",
                    "status": "READY"
                }
            ],
            "shareCommentary": {
                "text": "Some share text"
            },
            "shareMediaCategory": "VIDEO"
        }
    },
    "visibility": {
        "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "PUBLIC"
    }
}
```

And I get the error:

```
{"message":"com.linkedin.content.common.ResponseException: Writers of type person are not authorized to modify UserGeneratedContent.","status":401}
```

I have checked the access token that I am using and it correctly has the `r_member_social` and `w_member_social` permissions.

Are there some extra restrictions on personal profiles for UGC posts? Is there another way to create a video post for a personal profile (not a company)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked this question to the LinkedIn support desk. This is what they said:

> We do not currently support UGC videos on personal feeds via the API.
> The author would have to be an organization URN rather than a person
> URN. UGC video for personal feeds is definitely something we want to
> support eventually. However, there's not a concrete plan on when this
> will be made available.
>
> This is mentioned in our schema here:
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api#schema

Comment: Thanks! Where did you find their support desk? I could not find one before.

I also don't see this mentioned in their schema, did I miss it?